# Placing CefSharp dependencies into a specific directory

Tags: c#, .net, chromium, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am trying to create a .net **forms application** that uses **cefsharp**, but all of the cefsharp dependencies will be **placed and used from a specific directory** on the PC(let' s say C:\Chromium)

I have seen some entries but almost all of them are ancient, and using very old versions of cefsharp.

How can I achieve this with **cefsharp 96.0.142**?

I already tried

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <probing privatePath="libs"/>
</assemblyBinding>
```

but it didn' t work. I tried to put the C:\Chromium directory into the **PATH** env variable, but it didn' t work either. I always ended up with

*System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.WinForms'*

like exceptions. It looks like a very easy think to do but i got really stuck.

Any ideas would be really helpful. Thanks in advance

### EDIT#1 Code Fragment

```
this.chromiumComponent = new CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser();
this.SuspendLayout();
// 
// chromiumComponent
// 
this.chromiumComponent.ActivateBrowserOnCreation = false;
this.chromiumComponent.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
this.chromiumComponent.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.chromiumComponent.Name = "chromiumComponent";
this.chromiumComponent.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
this.chromiumComponent.TabIndex = 0;
```

I reference the CefSharp, CefSharp.Core, CefSharp.WinForms dlls from C:\Chromium directory. My intention is not to load the dlls from a subfolder of the project. Instead of that, I would like to place the dlls to a generic directory(like C:\Chromium) and my app to use them from this directory.

Comment: probing privatePath will only works for sub/child folders. How  exactly are you attempting to load from c:\chromium? What does your code look like?

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/3371 for for probing privatePath example

Comment: @amaitland my intention was not to load the dlls from a subfolder of the project. I want to place them to a directory and make my app(s) to load the dlls from that directory. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to use [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=netframework-4.6.2) event? If some assembly is missing in app output folder then `AssemblyResolve` event occurs and you can load assembly from different folder.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
    ...
}

private static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    var requestedName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
    var chromiumDirectory = @"C:\\C:\Chromium";
    var assemblyFilename = Path.Combine(chromiumDirectory, requestedName.Name + ".dll");
    if (File.Exists(assemblyFilename))
    {
        return Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFilename);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: it worked like a charm.. Thanks